# Jquery works in JSFiddle but not works in computer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsfiddle

This is the answer I get from jsfiddle. It's working on the fiddle part, but it's not working when I move it to my computer. I replaced the code in my program and also included all of the external resource library. However, it's still not working at all.

```js
var x = 1;

function appendRow() {
  var newTextBoxDiv = $(document.createElement('div'))
    .attr("id", 'TextBoxDiv' + x);
  // I ASSIGNED A CLASS CALLED INPUT TO THE ELEMENT YOU WANT TO SELECT
  newTextBoxDiv.after().html("<div class='form-group'><label class='control-label col-sm-3'  style='text-align:right;'>Date:</label><div class='col-sm-3'><div class='input-group date' ><span class='input-group-addon'><i class='fa fa-calendar'></i></span><input type='Date' class='form-control'  name='Dates'> <select class='form-control input' id='slct" + x + "' name='Branch''><option  disabled=''  selected=''>Please Select Leave Day</option> <option value='1' >1</option><option value='0.5' >0.5</option></select></div></span></div><div id='container" + x + "'></div></div>");
  newTextBoxDiv.appendTo("#div");
  x++;
}


function changeIt(rowIndex) {
  //i++; DO NOT INCREMENT I!!! IT WILL CREATE THE REFERRAL ERROR YOU HAD. BECAUSE THE FUNCTION WOULD BE REFERRING TO A NON-EXISTING INPUT ELEMENT. I REPLACED IT WITH ROWINDEX, WHICH IS INITIATED WHILE CALLING THE FUNCTION
  var select = document.getElementById("slct" + rowIndex);

  var divv = document.getElementById("container" + rowIndex);
  var value = select.value;

  if (value == 0.5) {
    toAppend = "<label class='control-label col-sm-1'>Time:</label><div class='col-sm-2'><div class='input-group date' id = 'date'> <span class='input-group-addon'><i class='fa fa-clock-o'></i></span><input type='time' class='form-control' ></div></div><div class='col-sm-2'><div class='input-group date' id = 'dates'> <span class='input-group-addon'><i class='fa fa-clock-o'></i></span><input type='time' class='form-control'  ></div></div>";
    divv.innerHTML = toAppend;
    return;
  }
  if (value == 1) {
    toAppend = "";
    divv.innerHTML = toAppend;
    return;
  }
}
$("#button").click(function() {
  appendRow();
});
$("#div").on("change", ".input", function() {
  //EXTRACT THE NUMBER FROM THE CLICKED ITEM'S ID
  let rowIndex = $(this).attr("id").replace(/.[^0-9]/g, "");
  changeIt(rowIndex);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div">
  <button value="Add Row" id="button">Add row</button>
</div>
```

Comment: is there error in console?

Comment: No previously there was an error in my previous version code,but now this is the answer modify and is works in fiddle but when i try to merge it in my code or even create a new file to handle this code also cannot get it work.
It should be able to add text box and when choose option 0.5 able to come out time textbox

Comment: `appendRow();` is inside `document . ready`? take it out ... this `changeIt(rowIndex);` as well

Comment: If take it out.Where should i place the appendRow function?

Comment: out side `document.ready` just pass the x as parameter to that function

Comment: I cant get you idea,could you help me modify it in jsfiddle or anywhere?

Comment: Is you JavaScript code is in a different js file??? Then you need to link it in HTML. Also keep your entire js code inside $(document).ready(function(){ . 
 // --- Here goes your code   });

Comment: No, the javascript file is put in the same file in HTML

Comment: put the entire js so we can see

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make sure your script is below the html for your button

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div">
    <button value="Add Row" id="button">Add row</button>
</div>
<!-- your js goes here -->
<script>
var x = 1;

    function appendRow() {
        var newTextBoxDiv = $(document.createElement('div'))
            .attr("id", 'TextBoxDiv' + x);
        // I ASSIGNED A CLASS CALLED INPUT TO THE ELEMENT YOU WANT TO SELECT
        newTextBoxDiv.after().html("<div class='form-group'><label class='control-label col-sm-3'  style='text-align:right;'>Date:</label><div class='col-sm-3'><div class='input-group date' ><span class='input-group-addon'><i class='fa fa-calendar'></i></span><input type='Date' class='form-control'  name='Dates'> <select class='form-control input' id='slct" + x + "' name='Branch''><option  disabled=''  selected=''>Please Select Leave Day</option> <option value='1' >1</option><option value='0.5' >0.5</option></select></div></span></div><div id='container" + x + "'></div></div>");
        newTextBoxDiv.appendTo("#div");
        x++;
    }


    function changeIt(rowIndex) {
        //i++; DO NOT INCREMENT I!!! IT WILL CREATE THE REFERRAL ERROR YOU HAD. BECAUSE THE FUNCTION WOULD BE REFERRING TO A NON-EXISTING INPUT ELEMENT. I REPLACED IT WITH ROWINDEX, WHICH IS INITIATED WHILE CALLING THE FUNCTION
        var select = document.getElementById("slct" + rowIndex);

        var divv = document.getElementById("container" + rowIndex);
        var value = select.value;

        if (value == 0.5) {
            toAppend = "<label class='control-label col-sm-1'>Time:</label><div class='col-sm-2'><div class='input-group date' id = 'date'> <span class='input-group-addon'><i class='fa fa-clock-o'></i></span><input type='time' class='form-control' ></div></div><div class='col-sm-2'><div class='input-group date' id = 'dates'> <span class='input-group-addon'><i class='fa fa-clock-o'></i></span><input type='time' class='form-control'  ></div></div>";
            divv.innerHTML = toAppend;
            return;
        }
        if (value == 1) {
            toAppend = "";
            divv.innerHTML = toAppend;
            return;
        }
    }
    $("#button").click(function() {
        console.log('test');
        appendRow();
    });
    $("#div").on("change", ".input", function() {
        //EXTRACT THE NUMBER FROM THE CLICKED ITEM'S ID
        let rowIndex = $(this).attr("id").replace(/.[^0-9]/g, "");
        changeIt(rowIndex);
    });</script>
```

Comment: alternatively you can wrap your script in a jquery onReady function, and just make sure to include jquery before your script

Comment: thanks you so much for you suggestion,it's now working perfectly :)

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with the solution

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
var x = 1;

    function appendRow() {
        var newTextBoxDiv = $(document.createElement('div'))
            .attr("id", 'TextBoxDiv' + x);
        // I ASSIGNED A CLASS CALLED INPUT TO THE ELEMENT YOU WANT TO SELECT
        newTextBoxDiv.after().html("<div class='form-group'><label class='control-label col-sm-3'  style='text-align:right;'>Date:</label><div class='col-sm-3'><div class='input-group date' ><span class='input-group-addon'><i class='fa fa-calendar'></i></span><input type='Date' class='form-control'  name='Dates'> <select class='form-control input' id='slct" + x + "' name='Branch''><option  disabled=''  selected=''>Please Select Leave Day</option> <option value='1' >1</option><option value='0.5' >0.5</option></select></div></span></div><div id='container" + x + "'></div></div>");
        newTextBoxDiv.appendTo("#div");
        x++;
    }


    function changeIt(rowIndex) {
        //i++; DO NOT INCREMENT I!!! IT WILL CREATE THE REFERRAL ERROR YOU HAD. BECAUSE THE FUNCTION WOULD BE REFERRING TO A NON-EXISTING INPUT ELEMENT. I REPLACED IT WITH ROWINDEX, WHICH IS INITIATED WHILE CALLING THE FUNCTION
        var select = document.getElementById("slct" + rowIndex);

        var divv = document.getElementById("container" + rowIndex);
        var value = select.value;

        if (value == 0.5) {
            toAppend = "<label class='control-label col-sm-1'>Time:</label><div class='col-sm-2'><div class='input-group date' id = 'date'> <span class='input-group-addon'><i class='fa fa-clock-o'></i></span><input type='time' class='form-control' ></div></div><div class='col-sm-2'><div class='input-group date' id = 'dates'> <span class='input-group-addon'><i class='fa fa-clock-o'></i></span><input type='time' class='form-control'  ></div></div>";
            divv.innerHTML = toAppend;
            return;
        }
        if (value == 1) {
            toAppend = "";
            divv.innerHTML = toAppend;
            return;
        }
    }
    $("#button").click(function() {
        console.log('test');
        appendRow();
    });
    $("#div").on("change", ".input", function() {
        //EXTRACT THE NUMBER FROM THE CLICKED ITEM'S ID
        let rowIndex = $(this).attr("id").replace(/.[^0-9]/g, "");
        changeIt(rowIndex);
    });
    });</script>
    </head>
<body>
<div id="div">
    <button value="Add Row" id="button">Add row</button>
</div>
<!-- your js goes here -->

    </body>
</html>
```

I think you forgot to add **$(document).ready(function(){});**

I tested in my local & it's working.